# SQL INSERT ERROR -117: number of values is not equal to number of columns

Tags: python, sql, db2

I am new to SQL and I am trying to experiment with different SQL queries. This time I have difficulties with INSERT INTO statement. Here is the table I defined:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
(
    EMP_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
    F_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    L_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    SSN CHAR(9),
    B_DATE DATE,
    SEX CHAR,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
    JOB_ID CHAR(9),
    SALARY DECIMAL(10,2),
    MANAGER_ID CHAR(9),
    DEP_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID)
);
```

It is empty. Now I am trying to populate table with some data and got stuck with -117 error. I am sure, I am doing some stupid mistake here, but despite all my experience in different areas, I don't see there. Here is INSERT INTO statement I am trying to execute:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (EMP_ID, F_NAME, L_NAME, SSN, SEX, ADDRESS, JOB_ID, SALARY, MANAGER_ID, DEP_ID)
VALUES ('E1001', 'John', 'Thomas', '123456', 'M', '5631 Rice, OakPark,IL', '100', 100000, '30001', '2'),
       ('E1002', 'Alice', 'James', '123457', 'F', '980 Berry ln, Elgin,IL', '200', 80000, '30002', '5'),
       ('E1003', 'Steve', 'Wells', '123458', 'M', '291 Springs, Gary,IL', '300', 50000, '30002', '5'),
       ('E1004', 'Santosh', 'Kumar', '123459', 'M', '511 Aurora Av, Aurora,IL', '400', 60000, '30004', '5'),
       ('E1005', 'Ahmed', 'Hussain', '123410', 'M', '216 Oak Tree, Geneva,IL', '500', 70000, '30001', '2'),
       ('E1006', 'Nancy', 'Allen', '123411', 'F', '111 Green Pl, Elgin,IL', '600', 90000, '30001', '2'),
       ('E1007', 'Mary', 'Thomas', '123412', 'F', '100 Rose Pl, Gary,IL', '650', 65000, '30003', '7'),
       ('E1008', 'Bharath', 'Gupta', '123413', 'M', '145 Berry Ln, Naperville,IL', '660', 65000, '30003', '7'),
       ('E1009', 'Andrea', 'Jones', '123414', 'F', '120 Fall Creek, Gary,IL', '234', 70000, '30003', '7'),
       ('E1010', 'Ann', 'Jacob', '123415', 'F', '111 Britany Springs,Elgin,IL', '220', 70000, '30004', '5');
```

and DB2 server returns the following error:

> SQL0117N  The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns or variables.  SQLSTATE=42802 SQLCODE=-117

Two questions here:

1. Why do I see this -117 error here? I counted endless times - number of columns and arguments are the same. Everything should be fine, but it is not.
2. How to set `B_DATE` column? I decided to leave `B_DATE` for later, but I still need to deal with it somehow. From information I found on Internet, DATE is stored as binary column. I have no idea how to encode it and ask DB2 server to store it properly. I just need some idea, I should be able to understand details myself.

Don't know if this is important, but I am working with DB2 using Python 3.x from Jupiter Notebook. Data I read from example CSV file. I can populate table from DB2 console using built-in CSV reader, but not from Jupiter Notebook.

Thanks

Comment: You say DB2, but have added a <sql-server> tag. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using DB2, but this query is so basic, so it should be similar for sql-server and for DB2 as well.

Comment: I get no error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d9089511b64c1cb45a761753cf307223

Comment: @jarlh, if I executed the same statements for sql-server, would I get the same error? I am puzzled if I am making basic SQL mistake, or if this is some nuances with DB2.

Comment: For the date: `update EMPLOYEES set B_date = date'1991-11-11';`

Comment: I did not see your answer before. Thanks, it seems this is some nuances with DB2. Will dig from here...

Comment: Can you assign a default value to Date and try ?

Comment: BTW, today most people use integer as data type for id columns. char(9) is a bit old-fashioned. (It's 2020 now, not 1985.)

Comment: @LymanZerga, did not work with default value to Date as well. Even more, I executed same statements in console myself and got no errors, but Jupiter Notebook still produces incorrect results. It seems, it is some issue with %SQL magic, or ibm_db_sa adapter, or something else from the same area.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug it!

For plain simple SQL in console all requests are correct, since plain simple SQL console ignores newlines to some extent. As far as I see, it is possible to create formatted SQL queries, using nice formatting rules. It is not the case for %SQL magic for IPython. If it sees newline, it believes that this is the end of query and tries to send it to the server. As a result server complains about missing values and produces error. As soon as I removed all newlines from the INSERT INTO query, I got statement passed without any errors.

I am not sure, but it seems to be error in %SQL magic for IPython.

Thanks everybody for their input and attention to this issue.